# Why is the font in tkinter not changing in size even though I am changing the number?

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically I have this GUI on tkinter and I want to change the size of the text on a label, this is my code:

```
Import tkinter as tk

#Main Page Attributes
main_frame = tk.Tk()
main_frame.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
main_frame["bg"] = "#000000"
main_frame.title("R-Net")

label_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
answer_label = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Welcome, Radwan", font=(70), bg = "black",fg = "white")
answer_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = tk.EW)
label_frame.place(relx=.5, y=0, anchor="n")
```

No matter how many times I change the number in font=(number) nothing changes. Why is that?

Comment: You are missing the font name in font=(70)

Answer (score 1):

You must actually give a font such as:

```
font = ("Courier", 70)
```

So:

```
answer_label = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Welcome, Radwan", font=(70), bg = "black",fg = "white")
```

Should instead be:

```
answer_label = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Welcome, Radwan", font = ("Courier", 70), bg = "black",fg = "white")
```